# Regex matching in Javascript returning the original string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm attempting to use Javascript Regex to select something in this fashion: `!something: somethingelse;` The exclamation point, the colon, and the semicolon have to be there, but the other parts can be any value. I attempted to do this:

```
"!test: value; random text here !another: valueagain;".match(/!(.*):(.*);/g);
```

This returns the original string, `!test: value; random text here !another: valueagain;`. Is there something I'm doing incorrectly, or is the Regex incorrect?

Comment: The entire string matches the regex, so you're doing it right, you're just not doing what you think you're doing.

Comment: what is your expected output, can you please share that?

Comment: Use non-greedy quantifiers.

Comment: @Denim The hope was that I would get an array of matches. Obviously that's not the case. It's only returning an array with the original string.

Comment: what is true return array with this example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As devnull suggested, use non-greedy quantifiers.

```
"!test: value; random text here !another: valueagain;".match(/!(.*?):(.*?);/g);
```

Output:

```
 [ '!test: value;', '!another: valueagain;' ]
```

In general, regular expression quantifiers like `*` are *greedy*, in the sense that they will try to match as large of an expression as possible.

The non-greedy versions `*?` will match only as much as they need to, to match.

Answer (score 0):

You are using greedy matchers, use non-greedy matchers like this

```
"!test: value; random text here !another: valueagain;".match(/!(.*?):(.*?);/g);
# [ '!test: value;', '!another: valueagain;' ]
```

`(.*):` consumes everything till the last `:` in the string, as it is greedy. That is why you are getting only a single string. Simply make it non-greedy by using `?`, like this `.*?`. This makes sure that it matches till the first `:`.

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/GdxxfrIoJ7cuM8yO)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.match(/!(.*?):(.*?);/g);
```

The added questionmarks make the `*` non-greedy, meaning it matches a string that's as short as possible.

Answer (score 0):

try this expression :

```
"!test: value; random text here !another: valueagain;".match(/![^!]*:[^!]*;/g);
```

return :

```
["!test: value;", "!another: valueagain;"]
```